# Access Token from my app doesn't work when I try to use it in a Facebook (FQL)

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am using `FQL`(mentioned below) to retrieve friends checkins, When I try my query on graph explorer it works fine and gives the required results so this means that there is no problem with the my query but when I try the same query in my app to do so using access token from my app it gives empty array,

I have given following permissions,

```
   friends_status  
   user_status
```

though I have tried with other permissions also.

`FQL` that I am using is:

```
SELECT checkin_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and timestamp > 1362787200.
```

I want to use this in making batch request in which I get the checking ids from this FQL and then use them to get information in a dependent query. I have other solutions but they are time taking.

Answer (score 1):

Your access token is probably expired. It can be tricky to keep up with access tokens, so instead try looking at having the user log in using a `Session` and managing its state. It'll automatically keep track of access tokens for you. Then you can do a `Request` via the 3.0 SDK and specify "fql" as a parameter.

If the user has logged in once, if you open up the session on app startup, it'll automatically log them in with a refreshed token.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the token from within your app?

I was having the same problem and to fix it I had to manually expire the token I was using at the time and also I hadn't added the permissions to the facebook app itslef from the facebook app console.